# How to create function to import CSV?

Tags: python

I'd like to create a function in Python to import CSV files from github, by just inputting the file name.

I tried the following code, but no dataframe is created. Can anyone give me a hand? Million thanks

```
import pandas as pd

def in_csv(file_name):
    file = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/file_name.csv'
    file_name = pd.read_csv(file, header = 0)
    
in_csv('csv_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to read à csv, but with à pandas.DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

def in_csv(file_name):
    file_path = f'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/{file_name}'
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header = 0)
    return df
    
df = in_csv('csv_name')
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you probably want to use a Python 3 F-string rather than a regular string. In this case, you would want to change your first line in the function to this:

```
file = f'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/{file_name}.csv'
```

The f'{}' syntax uses the value of the variable or expression within the brackets instead of the string literal you included.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Alian and @Aaron
Just add '.csv' after {file_name} and work perfect.

```
import pandas as pd

def in_csv(file_name):
    file_path = f'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/{file_name}**.csv**'  
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header = 0)
    return df
    
df = in_csv('csv_name')
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be part of the file name?